# What is a general form for the Laplace Transform of f(t) * f(t)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Suppose I know the laplace transform of $f(t)$. What would be the relation between laplace transform of $f(t)$ and laplace transform of $(f(t))^2$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "Multiplication" entry in [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of Laplace transform properties on Wikipedia gives a result for the Laplace transform of $f(t)g(t)$ as a convolution integral of the transforms of $f(t)$, $g(t)$.

Comment: I'm affraid you need the [Fourier/Laplace inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) for showing that it is $\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\sigma -i\infty}^{\sigma+i \infty} F(u)F(s-u)du$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laplace transform of $[f''[x]]^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32829/laplace-transform-of-fxn)