# What is the inverse Laplace Transformation of F(s)*G(s) utilizing convolution theorem?

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I have learnt about the Laplace convolution theorem:
$$\mathcal{L}[f(t)*g(t)]=\mathcal{L}[f(t)]\mathcal{L}[g(t)]$$
So I wonder if there any solution to 
$$\mathcal{L^{-1}}[F(s)*G(s)]=?$$
If there isn't, why there is in Fourier Transformation?

Comment: Is there any certain example in the mind?

Comment: I made it up in my mind. I just wonder why it is not the part of the theorem.

Comment: see there http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074411/what-is-a-general-form-for-the-laplace-transform-of-ft-ft#comment4260389_2074411 if you meant $F \ast G(s ) = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\sigma -i\infty}^{\sigma+i \infty} F(u)G(s-u)du$ then yes $\mathcal{L}^{-1}[F \ast G(s)] = f (t) g(t)$

Comment: Isn't $F(s)*G(s)=\int_0^s F(u)G(s-u)\,du$

Comment: Take a look at the last five rows of [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems)

Comment: I know what it is now. Thank you.